# Maximo -SoapUI “failed to load url” error when loading WSDL

Tags: web-services, soapui, maximo

We are on Maximo 7.5

I have created and deployed a web service in Maximo. I can load the wsdl of the service in the browser, however when I try to import it into SOAPUI, I get a "java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;"

When I try to access the service directly by using https://testurl:7003/meaweb/service/TestService, the browser pops up a dialog requesting username and password and shows an Error 401--Unauthorized error even when I pass the credentials that I successfully use to login to Maximo UI.

Can you please advise if there is any issue with the setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Download the wsdl from browser and save it in your local system.

Now import that saved wsdl to SoapUI.